# pass functions from module files to templates/views in rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lodash

I'd like to know if it's possible to pass functions from a module file on to all template files. Suppose I have a few functions in `func.js` file.

func.js

```
module.exports = {
 create_img = function(img,title,cl){
    var sb = '<a title="'+title+'" href="'+img+'"><img class="'+cl+'" src="'+img+'"></a>';
    return sb;
 },
 create_header = function(type){
    var header_html = "";
    if(type == 1){
       .....
    }else{
       .....
    }
    return header_html
 }  
}
```

In the server file, can I pass all of the functions on to the template files during rendering?

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, http = require('http').createServer(app)
, func = require('func')

app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){ 
  var filename = req.param("tagId");
  /* db.db.query('CALL load_page()') .....database code */ 
  res.render(filename+'.html',{result:database_result,functions:func}) 
}
```

In the template file (I use lodash for rendering):

```
 <% functions.create_header(0) %>
 <img src="<% functions.sb(i.src,'eslider_img') %>" alt"123">
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, could you please explain why you want to do this way?

Comment: @NarendraSoni, say I have multiple templates, I don't want to define the same functions over and over again for use in each of them.

Comment: Right approach is to only pass JSON data to client. But in your case you are passing function. So why you want to do this?